# Javascript. How to call an onclick function inside an object ?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this map area.

html:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="211,38,238,60" onclick="cancel()">


function cancel()
{
}
```

Now how can I do this inside an object?

js:

```
var images = {
    dosomething: {
        path: 'asdf.jpg',
        areas: [{
             coords: '211,38,238,60',
            text: 'dosomething',
            onclick: cancel()   // like this ?    
    }]
    },
  }
```

Comment: Sure you can. Why not?

Comment: `onclick: cancel,` without paranthesis. And someone has to use this object member.

Comment: Hmm, doesn`t work.

Comment: can you specify why it doesn't work ? Do you have an error ? Because @Holger's solution should work

Comment: Doesn`t give me anything.  When I click on the area nothing happens, but an alert should pop up

Comment: Like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/w4gcaz8v/1/

Comment: you should call alert("Hello") instead of images.dosomething.alert("Hello"). How do you call the onclick method in your html ? I think you should have an error, open the console to see what it is.

Comment: My html is separated from my js. The function cancel is also in the js file ^^.

Comment: if nothing happens, it means the onclick function is not called, you should post your html too otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4gcaz8v/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4gcaz8v/12/. I put an image though the image doesn`t work.

Comment: You don't use the onclick property of your object "image". But you use a property "goto" which is never defined. You define "images" but you reference "_images".

Comment: I think you are a bit wrong. Your first fiddle can't produce an alert. There's noone who calls cancel or onclick. There is only a define. If someone gets the object, he can call `obj.onclick()` and would get the alert. But there is noone who calls it. As I wrote in my first comment, there must be someone who uses the object member "onclick" (which may be "myclickfunction" too) because in your first posting you only define an object member with a name thats suggesting, it will be automatically called. But that's not so. It is *your* object and noone will do anything whithout *your* code.

Comment: Hmm, something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/w4gcaz8v/26/

Comment: This would be a deadloop. img.onclick == cancel. If you call img.onclick() you call cancel and cancel calls img.onclick().... What shall cancel() do and when should it be activated?

Comment: ok thank you =) Now it should only alert something to test it. But later I want something like this .   https://jsfiddle.net/3sqe6otf/1/